# Using Maven Cargo to Upload a Folder to a Remote UNIX system

Tags: maven, maven-3, maven-plugin, maven-cargo

I am thinking if this is possible. I am creating a resource/properties folder using maven and maven-ant-run-plugin. After the folder is created, I want to upload it to a remote UNIX server's file system.

Is there a way I can do it using `maven-cargo`? Most of the examples I see are for deploying to Tomcat containers. But mine is a plain directory upload to a remote machine.

There is the problem of username/password, but I will think about that later. But I just want to know if this possible first.

If there are other plugins that can do the job, please do let me know too.

Some examples would be really helpful.

Comment: In general Maven is not a deployment tool...It's a build tool..deployment on servers should usually being with other tools like ansible, chef, puppet, helm, Jenkins etc.. .

Comment: @khmarbaise Yeah. I know its a bit off-hand for maven. We use Jenkins as our deployment tool. But I am not an expert on it. With Maven I can still take a pot shot at it.